# Vue.js: Why is my v-else directive causing my element to be rendered multiple times?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying out vue.js, and so far it seems pretty nice.  I've run into some unexpected behavior though, and I can't tell if it's a bug, or intentional.  Under some circumstances, a `v-else` directive is causing my element to render multiple times.  I've reduced it to a minimal reproduction.

Try clicking the "go" button, and note that more and more "no" paragraphs appear.  I would expect that there would only ever be 1, at most.

```js
var d = { n: null };
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: d,
  methods: {
    go: function() { d.n = d.n == null ? 0 : null; }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.3/vue.min.js"></script>

<p v-if="n">yes</p>
<p v-else>no</p>

<button v-on:click="go()">go</button>
```

I can find workarounds that allow me to get my expected behavior, but before I start adding hacks to my code-base, what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Evan You verified that this is a bug.](http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/327/beginner-question-confusing-behavior-for-v-else/4)  And fixed it.

All before I woke up.